# VBA changes a cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

This is not an Earth stopping issue by any means, but I am curious why it only does it on this one cell, from my testing.

If I were to type into the VBA editor:

```
activesheet.[a1].select
```

VBA would show the line (after moving to a new line in the code) as:

```
Activesheet.[A1].Select
```

However, when I type in `[b1]`...the b stays lower case.  And this only seems to happen on cell B1.  Cell B2 will correct to `[B2]`.

Like I said...not a big issue, but it has made me curious...  Can anyone else replicate this?  I don't have a named range with the name 'b1' or one even using that field.  I haven't declared any variable or const as b1...I'm not sure what else it could be?  It happens in other workbooks too...not just one.

Is it something funky in VBA?  A setting somewhere??

**Edit:**
Using Excel 2007

As elmer007 pointed out, I can 'force' the change on other cells...but b1 is still corrected to b1 regardless.

---

I just did a Replace All from b1 to B1 and it still changed them all back to b1.

Comment: In my editor, whichever line I type last becomes the new auto-corrected version, and any previously typed lines are corrected to follow suit. So, if I type `activesheet.[a1].select` then it changes to `ActiveSheet.[a1].Select`. If I then type `activesheet.[A1].select` then it changes to `ActiveSheet.[A1].Select` AND changes the first line to `ActiveSheet.[A1].Select`. It will go back and forth depending on whichever one I type last. Not a replication of your situation, but information fwiw (Excel 2010, 14.0.7166.5000)

Comment: You didn't mention what version of Excel you are using, but on my XL 2013, only `Activesheet` auto corrects. The `[a1]` stays as I typed it.

Comment: Last meaning most recent, or last as in the statement closest to the bottom?  And I'm using 2007, sorry.

Comment: @Rdster For mine, "last" meaning most recent, regardless of line number. At first I thought I might have been able to replicate (maybe you had a lowercase "b1" somewhere else in your code), but mine won't change the most recently typed cell reference- it only updates any previously typed ones to match the latest